# Protect new VHDX in VM with Microsoft DPM

Tags: hyper-v, scdpm

I have a MS DPM 2012 R2 (Update 3) environment set up, backing up a Hyper-V 2012 R2 virtual machine from a 2-node cluster.

There are about 90 recovery points for this Hyper-V VM already.

I have now added 4 VHDX files to the VM, but I cannot find a way to have DPM recognize the addition and begin protecting those volumes.

I have tried the "Update-DPMProtectionGroup" powershell command, but it did not refresh as I expected.

I removed the VM from my protection group, re-added it and waited until the consistency check finished and this did not recognize the new VHDX files either.

Is this possible or am I stuck with deleting all my recovery points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time is short for this project, so I made the decision to delete my recovery points and try again.
I then discovered DPM still didn't recognize the new data.

Then I performed the following two steps:
- On the Agents page, refreshed both nodes of my cluster
- Within the "Modify Protect Group wizard" at the resource selection page, **I clicked "Clear Cache"**

That second step closed the wizard. When I opened it again and progressed to the Disk Allocation page it recognized the full data set and now I can proceed.